# What happends after a fetch request is aborted via AbortController?

Tags: javascript, http, web, async-await, fetch

If a `fetch` request in browser runtime is aborted via the signal of an `AbortController`, what happens afterward?

More specifically:

How will the HTTP request be terminated?
Will the sending/receiving of the HTTP request/response body proceed to finish if it is not fully sent out / received yet?

Will the underlying TCP connection be terminated? If so, is it terminated via a typical four-way handshake process or RESET directly? If so, is it still worth encouraging the use of AbortController against `fetch` considering it may take much time to establish a new TCP connection, especially when a bunch of requests is canceled consecutively such as auto-completing for search boxes?

If the underlying TCP connection will be re-used as usual, how could it be resumed from an incomplete HTTP request? (Is there some novel magic in HTTP/2 or QUIC?)

(I tried to search on the Internet, MDN, and the [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-abortcontroller) which defines `AbortController`, to find nothing mention how aborting works under the hood at all. And the codebase of those browsers is too obscure for me to even locate where the implemtation is.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same doubts and I [asked](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/discussions/2194) the maintainers of the official `fetch` implementation in Node.js. That's how it works there:

- The HTTP 1.1 standard does not offer a way to say "you know what, you can throw that response away" other than closing the TCP connection.
- Aborting a request means that we have to stop downloading and say to the server we're fine with not getting the response. Since there is no other way than closing on TCP level, Undici does this as soon as the response body is destroyed.
- Therefore, it might be worth consuming a response even if you don't want to use it, especially if the body size is not too high.